# How to get all the months based on a column value in Teradata

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I have a data like this from the db output.

```
yearmonth   orig_region_name            performance_percentage
2020-04     AMERICAS                    95.45
2020-04     ASIA PACIFIC                100.00
2020-04     EUROPE                      97.78

2020-04     GLOBAL                      97.76
2020-05     AMERICAS                    100.00
2020-05     EUROPE                      97.20
2020-05     GLOBAL                      97.21
```

But i need to add Asia pacific region which is missing for May month. The origin values are dynamic and it will change based on user selection parameters from UI.

```
yearmonth   orig_region_name            performance_percentage
2020-04     AMERICAS                    95.45
2020-04     ASIA PACIFIC                100.00
2020-04     EUROPE                      97.78
2020-04     GLOBAL                      97.76

2020-05     AMERICAS                    100.00
2020-05     ASIA PACIFIC                0
2020-05     EUROPE                      97.20
2020-05     GLOBAL                      97.21
```

How do i enforce this logic without impact much on my existing code? can someone help me on this.

Query -

```
SELECT yearmonth, orig_region_name, 
 (Cast(sum_net_volume AS DECIMAL(15,4)) 
  / NullIf(sum_monitored_volume ,0))*100 AS performance_percentage
 FROM
 (
SELECT 
Trim(Year(start_date)) || '-' || To_Char(start_date, 'MM') AS yearmonth, 
  orig_region_name,
  Sum(net_volume) AS sum_net_volume,
  Sum(monitored_vol) AS sum_monitored_volume
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' 
 AND group_code IN ('230') 
 AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR  (1=2)  )  
GROUP BY 1,2
) A
```

Comment: I understand you are a new contributor, if you could format the tables a little better using `table` in markdown, it will help a lot. Also, showing your results directly won't help. If you could show your tables - what are their columns and then what query you are using.

Comment: Thanks for syour suggestion Jay. Yes i am new to stack overflow. Will format the data for my upcoming queries. I have updated my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cte for this purpose. I have just used your query as inner query in cte.

```
 with cte as
(
 SELECT yearmonth, orig_region_name, 
 (Cast(sum_net_volume AS DECIMAL(15,4)) 
  / NullIf(sum_monitored_volume ,0))*100 AS performance_percentage
 FROM
 (
SELECT 
Trim(Year(start_date)) || '-' || To_Char(start_date, 'MM') AS yearmonth, 
  orig_region_name,
  Sum(net_volume) AS sum_net_volume,
  Sum(monitored_vol) AS sum_monitored_volume
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' 
 AND group_code IN ('230') 
 AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR  (1=2)  )  
GROUP BY 1,2
) A  
  )
  ,ym as (select distinct yearmonth from cte)
  ,regionname as (select distinct orig_region_name from cte)
  ,finalcte as (select * from ym cross join regionname)
  select f.yearmonth,f.orig_region_name,coalesce(cte.performance_percentage,0) from finalcte f left join cte
  on f.yearmonth=cte.yearmonth and f.orig_region_name=cte.orig_region_name
```

**Example with your provided dummy data:**

```
 create table yourtable (yearmonth varchar(10),  orig_region_name varchar(50), performance_percentage float);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-04'     ,'AMERICAS',                    95.45);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-04'     ,'ASIA PACIFIC',                100.00);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-04'     ,'EUROPE',                      97.78);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-04'     ,'GLOBAL',                      97.76);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-05'     ,'AMERICAS',                    100.00);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-05'     ,'EUROPE',                      97.20);
 insert into yourtable values('2020-05'     ,'GLOBAL',                      97.21);
```

Query:

```
  with cte as(
  SELECT yearmonth, orig_region_name, 
   performance_percentage
   from  yourtable 
   )
   ,ym as (select distinct yearmonth from cte)
   ,regionname as (select distinct orig_region_name from cte)
   ,finalcte as (select * from ym cross join regionname)
   select f.yearmonth,f.orig_region_name,coalesce(cte.performance_percentage,0) from finalcte f left join cte
   on f.yearmonth=cte.yearmonth and f.orig_region_name=cte.orig_region_name
```

Output:

| yearmonth | orig_region_name | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04 | AMERICAS | 95.45 |
| 2020-04 | ASIA PACIFIC | 100 |
| 2020-04 | EUROPE | 97.78 |
| 2020-04 | GLOBAL | 97.76 |
| 2020-05 | AMERICAS | 100 |
| 2020-05 | ASIA PACIFIC | 0 |
| 2020-05 | EUROPE | 97.2 |
| 2020-05 | GLOBAL | 97.21 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=400d4c9475ebfc0f8893df696669bc52)*

Comment: That's great. You are most welcome. Since it worked please accept this answer by clicking the green check. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata 16.20 supports Time Series Table & Aggregations:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(BEGIN(pd), 'YYYY-MM') AS YEARMONTH, orig_region_name, 
 (Cast(sum_net_volume AS DECIMAL(15,4)) 
  / NullIf(sum_monitored_volume ,0))*100 AS performance_percentage
 FROM
 (
SELECT 
  -- returns a date period
  CAST($TD_TIMECODE_RANGE AS PERIOD(DATE)) AS pd,
  orig_region_name,
  Sum(net_volume) AS sum_net_volume,
  Sum(monitored_vol) AS sum_monitored_volume
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATE '2020-07-01' AND DATE '2021-09-30' 
 AND group_code IN ('230') 
 AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR  (1=2)  )  
         -- times series aggregation, one row per month/region
GROUP BY TIME (CAL_MONTHS(1) AND orig_region_name)
         -- if the base table has no Primary Time Index TIMECODE must be specified
         USING TIMECODE (start_date)
         -- this creates the missing rows based on the date range in WHERE
         FILL (0)
) A
```

Your percentage calculation can probably be simplified, too. Assuming the *volumes* are decimal/integer columns:

```
100.00 * sum_net_volume
  / NullIf(sum_monitored_volume ,0) AS performance_percentage
```

Rule of thumb: *Multiply first, then divide.*

Answer (score 0):

You want all regions with all months. This is a cross join to start with.

```
SELECT
  yearmonths.yearmonth,
  regions.orig_region_name, 
  CASE WHEN data.yearmonth IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
    (Cast(data.sum_net_volume AS DECIMAL(15,4)) /
    NullIf(data.sum_monitored_volume, 0)) * 100
  END AS performance_percentage
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    Trim(Year(start_date)) || '-' || To_Char(start_date, 'MM') AS yearmonth
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' 
  AND group_code IN ('230') 
  AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR (1=2))
) yearmonths
CROSS JOIN
(
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    orig_region_name
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' 
  AND group_code IN ('230') 
  AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR (1=2))
) regions
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    Trim(Year(start_date)) || '-' || To_Char(start_date, 'MM') AS yearmonth, 
    orig_region_name,
    Sum(net_volume) AS sum_net_volume,
    Sum(monitored_vol) AS sum_monitored_volume
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' 
  AND group_code IN ('230') 
  AND (filter_BILL_RGN IN ('AM','EU') OR (1=2))  
  GROUP BY 1,2
) data ON data.yearmonth = yearmonths.yearmonth
       AND data.orig_region_name = regions.orig_region_name
ORDER BY yearmonths.yearmonth, regions.orig_region_name;
```

Remove conditions from `yearmonths` and `regions`, if you don't want to restrict them to those that have data.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I will check this approach.